# Conjectured primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample for the following claim :

> Let $n$ be a natural number , $n>2$ and $n \neq 9$ . Then $n$ is prime if and only if
>
> $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(2^k-1\right)^{n-1} \equiv n \pmod{2^n-1}$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVkjtPwzAQgPf-CpMltjAVLQNqwRISYgMmtr7kJJfEamJb9plWqvjvuIlZQELqDZbvzvfdy42dwqfsaIbgkWomTl740NO9mHF9M-OdqpG-mYrOt_uozrfRyLb0fDL24ACD04PfJ58Qmn1lbFJBTZ5bKPcRupyQs6ia6Me7pERJ0a8S4fhytI5m63W84uk99AU40gePpADSOIhPHMFWaoIHcxX5bKRAd4YKsfiH6tHFGq5_4ER5Yj2EylinevgNa-y0DrpEZfSulF2aTMZXesOmXjZAY4voAlyY8U8ufyGhNL01XmGiPCkdZyJLHCa9o1oobQPuCnOks8X9Hc_HKS5zflAVtmJ-y7gc-hIeOijROLrKhxXlG14ERKO9-Iid8U4W0Ik8Z2lzYxgRZPgqo8bI4PKtOZBkihWzb4--uRk=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) .

GUI application that implements this algorithm can be found [here](https://github.com/PedjaTerzic/COP) .

Android app that implements this algorithm can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n4ual3y3v0hvvua/ConjectureOnPrimality.apk?dl=0) .

I was searching for a counterexample using the following two PARI/GP programs :

```
CE1(n1,n2)=
{
forcomposite(n=n1,n2,
if((Mod(sum(k=1,n-1,(2^k-1)^(n-1)),2^n-1)==n),print("n="n))) 
}
```

---

```
CE2(n1,n2)=
{
forprime(n=n1,n2,
if(!(Mod(sum(k=1,n-1,(2^k-1)^(n-1)),2^n-1)==n),print("n="n))) 
}
```

**Remark**

More generally we can formulate the following criterion :

> Let $b$ and $n$ be a natural numbers , $b\geq 2$ , $n>2$ and $n \neq 9$ . Then $n$ is prime if and only if
>
> $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(b^k-1\right)^{n-1} \equiv n \pmod{\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}}$

**EDIT**

Improved PARI/GP programs for counterexample search :

```
CE1(b,n1,n2)=
{
forcomposite(n=n1,n2,
s=sum(k=1,n-1,lift(Mod(b^k-1,(b^n-1)/(b-1))^(n-1)));
if((Mod(s,(b^n-1)/(b-1))==n),print("n="n)))
}
```

---

```
CE2(b,n1,n2)=
{
forprime(n=n1,n2,
s=sum(k=1,n-1,lift(Mod(b^k-1,(b^n-1)/(b-1))^(n-1)));
if(!(Mod(s,(b^n-1)/(b-1))==n),print("n="n)))
}
```

Comment: Can you say something about how you came up with this?

Comment: @Henrik This was inspired by [Giuga's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh%E2%80%93Giuga_conjecture) and [Vantieghem's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantieghems_theorem)

Comment: This works amazingly well! But why the condition $n \neq 9$?

Comment: @Vincent Because $9$ is a pseudoprime (composite number that passes a test) .

Comment: Very impressive. In the link you gave I get error messages due to the lenght of number and computations when n>10000, but I found neither pseudoprime nor prime given as composite for four-digits numbers.

Comment: Well yes, I can see that it is a pseudoprime but is there a conceptual explanation? Did you know on forehand that 9 would be the exception? If it just randomly showed up you might expect others would do so as well (although apparently they do not, given @Evargalo 's comment

Comment: @Vincent: note that my tries were anything but systematic, I made about 10 or 15 tries but didn't prove that it always works.

Comment: When n is prime, n-1 is the Euler totient number for the prime. Therefore, the product is taken as k runs through all comprimes less than the prime. The modulus will always be true for primes.

Comment: nice, but it is not practically usable because of its exponential storage and running rime.

Comment: @FredKline I'm not seeing it; I am assuming by "product" you are referring to the sum, but I don't know of any results relating the totient function working mod $2^n-1$

Comment: @PeđaTerzić so, you do not have a proof that this test works?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas No , I don't have a proof .

Comment: Not sure how far others have tested, but I've tested up to around 5400 and there were no other counterexamples other than 2 and 9.

Comment: @Wojowu How did you check it?

Comment: Using a Sage script, unfortunately I didn't save it, but there should be no problem recreating it.

Comment: @Wojowu did you use the same direct approach as the OP or did you implement some refinements? Which one?

Comment: @Wojowu if you don't add @ + my username to your comment, I won't get a notification that you have responded to my comment.

Comment: @miracle173 The only improvement is using modular exponentiation. Also, sorry, I forgot to add the @ thing before.

Comment: @Wojowu How long did it take to check up to n=5400?

Comment: @miracle173 I can't remember, probably around 20 minutes?

Comment: I don't see a benefit in this test, this one will run in $O(n)$ time unless you shortcut the sum somehow, while ordinary trial division will run much faster in $O(\sqrt{n})$ ...

Comment: @Sil https://ibb.co/y4m9q6n

Answer (score 13):

This is a partial answer.

This answer proves that if $n$ is an odd prime and $b\ge 2$ is an integer, then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(b^k-1\right)^{n-1}\equiv n \pmod{\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}}$$
Proof :

Let $N:=\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}$.

By the binomial theorem,
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(b^k-1\right)^{n-1}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}(b^k)^{j}(-1)^{n-1-j}\\\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}(b^k)^{j}(-1)^{n-1-j}\\\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{0}(b^k)^{0}(-1)^{n-1-0}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}(b^k)^{j}(-1)^{n-1-j}\\\\&=(n-1)\cdot (-1)^{n-1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}(b^k)^{j}(-1)^{n-1-j}\tag1\end{align}$$

Since $n$ is an odd prime, we have $(-1)^{n-1}=1$, so

$$\begin{align}(1)&=n-1+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}(b^k)^{j}(-1)^{n-1-j}\\\\&=n-1+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}(-1)^{n-1-j}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(b^j)^{k}\tag2\end{align}$$

By the way,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(b^j)^{k}=\frac{(b^n)^{j}-b^j}{b^j-1}=\frac{((b-1)N+1)^j-b^j}{b^j-1}\tag3$$
By the binomial thorem,
$$\begin{align}(3)&=\frac{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{j}\binom{j}{m}(b-1)^mN^m\right)-b^j}{b^j-1}\\\\&=\frac{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{j}\binom{j}{m}(b-1)^mN^m\right)+1-b^j}{b^j-1}\\\\&=\frac{1-b^j}{b^j-1}+\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{j}\binom{j}{m}(b-1)^mN^m}{b^j-1}\\\\&=-1+\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{j}\binom{j}{m}(b-1)^mN^m}{b^j-1}\\\\&=-1+\frac{N}{b^j-1}\sum_{m=1}^{j}\binom{j}{m}(b-1)^{m}N^{m-1}\tag4\end{align}$$

Now, we use that if $n$ is an odd prime, then either $\gcd(N,b^j-1)=n$ and $b\equiv 1\pmod n$ or $\gcd(N,b^j-1)=1$ holds for $1\le j\le n-1$. (The proof is written at the end of this answer.)

Case 1 : When $\gcd(N,b^j-1)=n$ with $b\equiv 1\pmod n$,
$$\begin{align}(4)&=-1+\frac{N}{(b-1)(b^{j-1}+b^{j-2}+\cdots +b+1)}\sum_{m=1}^{j}\binom{j}{m}(b-1)^{m}N^{m-1}\\\\&=-1+\frac{N}{b^{j-1}+b^{j-2}+\cdots +b+1}\sum_{m=1}^{j}\binom{j}{m}(b-1)^{m-1}N^{m-1}\end{align}$$
Now, since $b^{j-1}+b^{j-2}+\cdots +b+1\equiv j\not\equiv 0\pmod n$, we have that $$\frac{1}{b^j-1}\sum_{m=1}^{j}\binom{j}{m}(b-1)^{m}N^{m-1}=\frac{1}{b^{j-1}+b^{j-2}+\cdots +b+1}\sum_{m=1}^{j}\binom{j}{m}(b-1)^{m-1}N^{m-1}$$
is an integer.

Case 2 : When $\gcd(N,b^j-1)=1$, we have that 
$$\frac{1}{b^j-1}\sum_{m=1}^{j}\binom{j}{m}(b-1)^{m}N^{m-1}$$
is an integer.

So, in either case, we have
$$(4)\equiv -1\pmod N\tag5$$

Therefore, from $(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$, we have
$$\begin{align}(1)&\equiv n-1-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}(-1)^{n-1-j}\qquad\pmod{N}\\\\&\equiv n-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}(-1)^{n-1-j}\cdot 1^j\qquad\pmod{N}\\\\&\equiv n-(1-1)^{j}\qquad \pmod{N}\\\\&\equiv n\qquad\pmod{N}\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

---

Finally, let us prove that if $n$ is an odd prime and $b\ge 2$ is an integer, then either $\gcd(N,b^j-1)=n$ and $b\equiv 1\pmod n$ or $\gcd(N,b^j-1)=1$ holds for $1\le j\le n-1$ where $N=\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}$.

Proof :

Let $D=\gcd(N,b^j-1)$. Then, we have $b^n\equiv 1\pmod D$ and $b^j\equiv 1\pmod D$. Let $s$ be the smallest $t$ such that $b^t\equiv 1\pmod D$. There exist non-negative integers $u,r$ such that $n=us+r$ with $0\le r\lt s$. Then,
$$1\equiv b^n=b^{us}\cdot b^r=(b^s)^u\cdot b^r\equiv b^r\implies r=0$$
So, $n=us$. Similarly, there exists a non-negative integer $v$ such that $j=vs$. Since $\gcd(n,j)=1$, we have $s=1$ and $b\equiv 1\pmod D$.

Now, $$0\equiv N=\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}=b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}+\cdots +b+1\equiv n\pmod D$$
from which we have $D=1$ or $D=n$.$\qquad\blacksquare$

Answer (score 6):

Just a remark which is a little long for a comment:

If we forget about the two and also about the generalization to other numbers for a second and look at polynomials instead, i.e. consider the polynomial
$$p_n(x) := \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x^k-1)^{n-1}$$
and then reduce this modulo $x^n-1$, the reduced polynomials for $p_n$ when $n$ is prime have a very nice form, namely:
$$p_n(x) \equiv n - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i \mod{x^n-1}.$$
Now it is clear that if we input $2$ (or $b$), the sum will exactly be $2^n-1$ resp $\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}$, so we get $n$ as claimed.

This is, unfortunately, not yet a proof for your claim, but it suggests that there is an even stronger structure behind it, that goes beyond natural numbers. Note that the polynomial $p_9$ does not have this nice structure, meaning that this strange case could be excluded when viewing it in the polynomial world.